# What does empty square bracket mean in jsonpath with Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

The following kubectl expression returns the image version:

`kubectl get po nginx -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[].image}{"\n"}'`

But what does the '[]' signify exactly? i get that it is saying image is a child of containers which is a child of spec but why the *empty* square bracket?

Comment: Did the following answer helped you ? If it did, can you accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{.spec.containers}` will return an array. Using empty square bracket means the **desired value is an array.**

you can validate this by running the following, the output of the query is an array:

```
 kubectl get po mongo  -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers}{"\n"}'
[{"image":"mongo","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"mongo","ports":[{"containerPort":27107,"protocol":"TCP"}],"resources":{},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount","name":"default-token-c949d","readOnly":true}]},{"image":"nginx","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"nginx","ports":[{"containerPort":80,"protocol":"TCP"}],"resources":{},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount","name":"default-token-c949d","readOnly":true}]}]
```

when used with `[]`, we expect the output of `.spec.containers` to be array and process it already :

```
kubectl get po mongo  -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[]}{"\n"}'
{"image":"mongo","imagePullPolicy":"Always","name":"mongo","ports":[{"containerPort":27107,"protocol":"TCP"}],"resources":{},"terminationMessagePath":"/dev/termination-log","terminationMessagePolicy":"File","volumeMounts":[{"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount","name":"default-token-c949d","readOnly":true}]}
```